# Problem with binary units using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to use the `siunitx` package to display binary units. I have loaded the package using `\usepackage[detect-weight=true, load-configurations=binary]{siunitx}`but when I try to type `\SI{4}{\gibi \byte}` I get this error:
`siunitx error: "prefix-only" Prefix with no unit. ...giga \hertz} así como \SI{4}{\giga \byte}`.

I've read that the package version matters when using binary units, mine is `siunitx 2017/02/01 v2.7c`

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the package option `binary-units=true` (or just `binary-units`), as specified in the documentation:

> Binary data is expressed in units of bits and bytes. These are
>   normally given prefixes which use powers of two, rather than the
>   powers of ten used by the SI prefixes. As these binary prefixes are
>   closely related to the SI prefixes, they are defined by siunitx but do
>   have to be loaded using binary-units = true (or simply binary-units)
>   The units \bit and \byte are then also available.

The option `load-configurations` is deprecated in favor of the `abbrevations`, `binary-units` and `version-1-compatibility` options.

This compiles for `siunitx v2.7c from 2017/02/01`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{4}{\gibi\byte}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note, the option `binary-units` has been removed in v3.0.0 (2021-05-17), see [here](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#removed). I think binary units are now loaded by default. So it is still compatible, since the option will just not be used anymore (but issue a warning).